# jquery append to window

Tags: jquery, window, append

how can i append a div directly to the window object?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
      <body>
           <div><div>
           <ul>..</ul>
      </body>
</html>
```

and i want to append an element after the ul, but not something like $('ul').after(element), i just want to append it directly to body. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$("body").append(element);` or `$(element).appendTo("body");`